# MySQL strange EXPLAIN PLAN results

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

I'm trying to tune a query inside of a stored procedure that runs fine the first time I call the stored procedure, but slows to a crawl on subsequent calls.

I've commented some of the original query out, so please forgive me if it looks like there is unnecessary nesting:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT
  glm.store_id,
  glm.account_balance
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    m.store_id,
    m.account_number,
    ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(gl.account_balance), 0.00), 2) AS account_balance
  FROM
    account_map m
  LEFT JOIN (
    select
      store_id,
      account_number_dms,
      sum(account_balance) AS account_balance
    FROM
      general_ledger
    WHERE
      account_date >= startDate
    AND
      account_date < endDate
    GROUP BY
      store_id, account_number_dms
  ) AS gl
    ON gl.store_id = m.store_id
    AND gl.account_number_dms = m.account_number_dms
  WHERE
    m.map_type = mapType
  AND m.store_id IN (
    SELECT store_id
    FROM store
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(store_id, storeIdList)
  )
  GROUP BY
    m.store_id,
    m.account_number
) AS glm;
```

The first time I call this, I get a reasonable EXPLAIN plan:

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    26550   100.00  NULL
2   DERIVED store   index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 3   NULL    5   100.00  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED m   ref PRIMARY,IX_store_id__account_number__sales_account__dept_id IX_store_id__account_number__sales_account__dept_id 3   id_data_1.store.store_id    531 100.00  Using where; Using index
2   DERIVED <derived3>  ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 66  id_data_1.store.store_id,id_data_1.m.account_number_dms 10  100.00  Using where
3   DERIVED general_ledger  index   NULL    PRIMARY 69  NULL    496442  100.00  Using where
```

But if I call it a second time:

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1318053510  100.00  NULL
2   DERIVED store   index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 3   NULL    5   100.00  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED m   ref PRIMARY,IX_store_id__account_number__sales_account__dept_id IX_store_id__account_number__sales_account__dept_id 3   id_data_1.store.store_id    531 100.00  Using where; Using index
2   DERIVED <derived3>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    496442  100.00  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
3   DERIVED general_ledger  index   NULL    PRIMARY 69  NULL    496442  100.00  Using where
```

Whoa, holy cow!  That first line is jumping from `26550` rows to `1318053510` rows.  1.3 billion!  Where is that coming from?  I don't have more than a few hundred thousand rows.  Is it trying to cache something?  It's slowing down from 250 milliseconds to nearly 5 seconds.

Comment: Your JOIN might multiply your estimated records a bit. And the `m.store_id IN` will give a poor estimate. Avoid IN statements where possible (use JOINS instead) to avoid really poor performance

Comment: Thanks @NorbertvanNobelen.  I've tried a few things and I'm getting some better performance.  For example, the first time I run the stored proc is lightning fast now, but the second time it drops in speed more than 10 times.  It really seems to be related to wrapping it in a stored proc - the query alone is pretty fast.  That's the real mystery here.